# Как задать для объекта конструктор?

Tags: javascript, pure_js

Здравствуйте. Как внутри функции задать что-то вроде конструктора, который обязательно будет вызываться при таком создании объекта (в конструкторе должна быть некая последовательность действий и инициализация одной переменной):

```
var clazz = new myFunction(op);
```

Желательно, чтобы он был внутри функции:

```
function myFunction(op) {
    constructor(){
    ... ... ... ...
    }
}
```

PS. Без использования библиотек.

Comment: То есть в данном случае myFunction не конструтор да?

Comment: обновил

Comment: <small><i>Cоветую почитать книгу <b>JavaScript DesignPatterns</b></i></small>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

myFunction и является конструктором.

```
function myFunction(op) {
    this.var1 = '';

 //...
}
```

P.S. если вы хотите ИМЕННО функцию конструктор, которая обязательно будет вызываться, то...

```
 function myFunction(op) {

      this.__constructor = function(){ 
        this.var1 = '';
      }
      //БИНГО:
        this.__constructor();
     //...
    }
```